# about pass php variable to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I got a html5 upload script from
http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/

can i pass php variable to js?
in this html5 upload script
the script.js call the post_file.php to upload file
in post_file.php

```
$rand = time();
```

i set the rand is the filename
for example uploaded filename: 1331956640.jpg

can i pass this $rand to script.js?
because i can't print the result in php, only can print something in script.js

this is the html5 upload script download link from tutorialzine
[enter link description here](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/html5-file-upload.zip)

sorry my english not good, thank

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
var my_javascript_var = <?php echo $rand; ?>
</script>
```

or

```
<input id="my_rand_value" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rand;?>" />
```

in js do so

```
var my_javascript_var = $("#my_rand_value").val():
```

Comment: increase your reputation by marking the Tik to the answer that helped you

Answer (score 4):

It's not actually about "passing" a variable from PHP to JavaScript.

Remember that PHP is a server-side scripting language, and JavaScript resides on a client's browser.

So, you could actually... write directly any javascript you wish from your PHP script.

Let's say, you've got a `$a` variable... then you could simply enter it in your javascript code like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var a = <?php echo $a; ?>
</script>
```

**However :**

If what you mean is to actually use the `$a` var while the page has loaded, or retrieve the result in some way, WITHOUT reloading, then what you probably need is Ajax.

To use AJAX, I would either suggest :

- the jQuery `load` method
- using some [ready-made AJAX object](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Ultimate_Ajax_Object)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<script>
    var javascriptvar = <?=$rand ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to ....

```
<script>
  var rand = new Date().getTime();
</script>
```

this uses only JavaScript to get the same result

Comment: thank^_^ i will use this first~
but can i get the server time?
because my server time is faster then this result:]

Comment: also this result is longer then php time()
js:13319xxxxxxxx  (13digits)
php:13319xxxxx   (10digits)

Comment: js time is in milliseconds you need to divide by 1000 to get php time (in seconds)

Comment: thank. but how can i get the server time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="your.js"></script>

...

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="your_js_function(<?php  echo $time; ?>);"><img src="your_button.gif" /></a>
```